# How resolve the issues in deserializing the xml returned by a rest service?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I am getting the following error when i tried to deserialize the xml of rest service respone from a web client.

> {System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document
>   (1, 2). ---> System.InvalidOperationException:  was not
>   expected.    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderRoot.Read6_Root()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
>   xmlReader, String encodingStyle, Object events)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(Stream stream)
>   at XmlParser.MainPage.DeserializeXmlData(Stream stream)    at
>   XmlParser.MainPage.<>c_*DisplayClass6.b*_5(Object s,
>   OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.OnOpenReadCompleted(OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
>   at System.Net.WebClient.OpenReadOperationCompleted(Object arg)}

The Xml returned by service is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns0:Response xmlns:ns0="urn:ae:gov:testwebsite:uniqueness:genericcontentsrs:1">
    <GenericContents>
        <ModuleId>1296</ModuleId>
        <Title>Getting around</Title>
        <Description>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum., <a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">google.com</a>, provides useful information. People often rely on landmarks to give directions.<br /> <br />Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. gmk&rsquo;s Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</Description>
        <BuildingId>0</BuildingId>
        <GeoCoordinateX/>
        <GeoCoordinateY/>
    </GenericContents>
</ns0:Response>
```

I have tried by putting XmlRoot attribute for the class,but still it gives the same error.

Following the class i have used to desserialize the xml

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ns0:Response",)]
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ns0:Response")]
        public nsResponse _nsResponse { get; set; }  
    }

    public class nsResponse
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GenericContents")]
        public GenericContents _GenericContents { get; set; } 
    }

    public class GenericContents
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ModuleId")]
        public string _ModuleId { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Title")]
        public string _Title { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Description")]
        public string _Description { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BuildingId")]
        public string _BuildingId { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GeoCoordinateX")]
        public string _GeoCoordinateX { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GeoCoordinateY")]
        public string _GeoCoordinateY { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is the code iam using for deserializing

```
private Root DeserializeXmlData(System.IO.Stream stream)
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
            Root result = (Root)ser.Deserialize(stream);
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Show us the code that you are using to deserialize that xml

Comment: @Alberto i have added the code.please find my edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is due to the empty node values in the Xml file returned by the rest service.In the xml file you have two empty node values GeoCoordinateX and GeoCoordinateY.

and the issue is resolved by changing the deserializing class as below.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ns0:Response",)]
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ns0:Response")]
        public nsResponse _nsResponse { get; set; }  
    }

    public class nsResponse
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GenericContents")]
        public GenericContents _GenericContents { get; set; } 
    }

    public class GenericContents
    {
        private string moduleIdField;

        private string titleField;

        private string descriptionField;

        private string buildingIdField;

        private string geoCoordinateXField;

        private string geoCoordinateYField;

        public string ModuleId
        {
            get
            {
                return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(moduleIdField)) ? moduleIdField.ToString() : "";
            }
            set
            {
                this.moduleIdField = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? (value).ToString() : "";
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(titleField)) ? titleField.ToString() : "";
            }
            set
            {
                this.titleField = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? (value).ToString() : "";
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Description
        {
            get
            {
                return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(descriptionField)) ? descriptionField.ToString() : "";
            }
            set
            {
                this.descriptionField = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? (value).ToString() : "";
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string BuildingId
        {
            get
            {
                return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(buildingIdField)) ? buildingIdField.ToString() : "";
            }
            set
            {
                this.buildingIdField = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? (value).ToString() : "";
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string GeoCoordinateX
        {
            get
            {
                return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(geoCoordinateXField)) ? geoCoordinateXField.ToString() : "";
            }
            set
            {
                this.geoCoordinateXField = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? (value).ToString() : "";
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string GeoCoordinateY
        {
            get
            {
                return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(geoCoordinateYField)) ? geoCoordinateYField.ToString() : "";
            }
            set
            {
                this.geoCoordinateYField = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? (value).ToString() : "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The *name* of the element is `Response`, not `ns0:Response`. Namespace **prefixes** aren't, formally, part of the name. The following two pieces of xml are, informationally, identical:

```
<a:b xmlns:a="urn:damiens_namespace"/>
```

and,

```
<y:b xmlns:y="urn:damiens_namespace"/>
```

So when you declare them in code, what's important is the namespace, not the prefix:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Response",
         Namespace="urn:ae:gov:testwebsite:uniqueness:genericcontentsrs:1")]
    public class Root
    {
```

---

(Looking again at your code, I'm not really sure what the `Root` class is meant to be for. I'd have expected `XmlRoot()` to be applied to the `nsResponse` class and for you to pass that class to `XmlSerializer`)

Comment: @damien-the-unbeliever Thanks, but Now i am getting the `An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.Serialization.ni.dll but was not handled in user` Help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`ns0` is an undeclared prefix in the xml document, which is most likely causing your error.

If it's necessary, then it needs to be wrapped in an envelope with an `xmlns:n0="http:somenamespace"` attribute in the envelope element.

Comment: I disagree. From [Namespaces in XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/): "The namespace prefix, unless it is xml or xmlns, MUST have been declared in a namespace declaration attribute in either the start-tag of the element where the prefix is used or in an ancestor element"

Comment: You are correct.  I did some more playing around with the xml and code supplied and boy oh boy does c# not like that xml for some reason.